# Recover lost data after mysqldump command overwritten existing data

Tags: mysql

I wanted to add additional table to existing DB from one PC to another using mysqldump. 
This is command I ran
`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root -p <database> < <table_name_copied_from_another_PC>.sql`

I ended up overwriting, not intentionally, all of my existing data on destination PC. Now I lost all existing data on destination PC, which I really need. 
How do I recover this data? I've read about bin logs, I've executed following command:
`mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;`
Result was this:

```
+----------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Log_name                   | File_size | Encrypted |
+----------------------------+-----------+-----------+
| DESKTOP-AFID0G9-bin.000001 |       179 | No        |
| DESKTOP-AFID0G9-bin.000002 |     43514 | No        |
| DESKTOP-AFID0G9-bin.000003 |      8848 | No        |
| DESKTOP-AFID0G9-bin.000004 |      7221 | No        |
| DESKTOP-AFID0G9-bin.000005 |    162569 | No        |
+----------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Above is the result. But it seems that any of these Log_name files cannot be found:
So I run this line: 
`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqlbinlog DESKTOP-AFID0G9-bin.000001 | mysql -u root -p <database>`
And this is what I see:
`mysqlbinlog: File 'DESKTOP-AFID0G9-bin.000001' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
ERROR: Could not open log file
Enter password: ***********`
And nothing changes after I entered password

Maybe this is not right approach...

Comment: next time make a backup before running a script that you didn't inspect  in detail. for that matter make **always** a backup.

Comment: You're hosed, but out of morbid curiosity what are the first few lines of the sql script?

Comment: @Bohemian, it was copied from MacBook so line was: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump - root -p <database> <table> > /Users/my_user_on_Mac/Documents/name_of_File.sql`

Comment: No, the first few lines of the *sql script*, not the command. ie what you called `name_of_File.sql`

Comment: Lesson learned.

Comment: @Bohemian, sorry for late update. It was an insert query before I executed command line mysqldump

Comment: @AlexanderBurdeyniy you are still not answering my question of what command were in the file. Anyway, I suspect it was drop database...